# Texto em Input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Porque eu não consigo digitar texto no input **".tarefa-edit"** que foi criado com o **jQuery**?

```js
$(function(){
    function onTarefaDeleteClick(){
        $(this).parent('.tarefa-item').hide('slow', function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    $('.tarefa-delete').click(onTarefaDeleteClick);
});
$(function(){
    function onTarefaItemClick(){
        var text = $(this).children('.tarefa-texto').text();
        var html = '<input type="text" ' + 'class="tarefa-edit" value="' + text + '">';
        $(this).html(html);
        $('.tarefa-edit').keydown(onTarefaEditKeydown);
    }
    $('.tarefa-item').click(onTarefaItemClick); //
});
function onTarefaEditKeydown(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        savePendingEdition($(this));
    }
}
function savePendingEdition(tarefa){
    console.log('...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo">
    <h2>TODO List</h2>
    <input type="text" id="tarefa">
    <div id="tarefa-lista">
        <div class="tarefa-item">
            <div class="tarefa-texto">Comprar pão</div>
            <div class="tarefa-delete"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para que serve a função **onTarefaEditKeydown**? Pq se vc está no input de cima e dá um tab para o input criado ele recebe texto normalmente, mas, se clicar no input ele não recebe mais o foco.

Comment: `.keydown` não costuma funcionar com elementos criados dinamicamente, sugiro trocar por `$(document).on('keydown', ".tarefa-edit",onTarefaEditKeydown) `.  Teste e informe se deu certo, não consegui testar porque não tem um exemplo testável na sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está ocorrendo que você associou a função **onTarefaItemClick** ao evento "click" da tag **`<div class="tarefa-item">`**, então quanto você clicar na caixa **`<input type="text" class="tarefa-edit" value="">`** que está dentro da tag **`<div class="tarefa-item">`** o evento  "**onTarefaItemClick**" e chamado novamente recriando a caixa de texto, você desabilitar evento **onclick**  da tag **`<div class="tarefa-item">`** após criação da caixa de texto o problema não vai ocorre:

```
$(function(){
    function onTarefaItemClick(){
        $('.tarefa-item').unbind();
        var text = $(this).children('.tarefa-texto').text();
        var html = '<input type="text" ' + 'class="tarefa-edit" value="' + text + '">';
        $(this).html(html);
        $('.tarefa-edit').keydown(onTarefaEditKeydown);
    }
    $('.tarefa-item').click(onTarefaItemClick); //
});
```